# Trying out an angularjs directive, not really working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive

So I'm trying to work with a directive, everything I found on the internet looks quite the same as what I've got.

This is the directive I made:

```
angular.module('App');

App.directive("scrollBottom", ["$interval", function ($interval) {
return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        $('a').click(function () {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $($(this).attr('#myAnchor')).offset().top
            }, 40000);
            return false;
        });
     }
  }
}]);
```

This is how I wanted to call the directive:

```
<button scrollBottom>Click me!</button>
```

But the sad part is that it doesn't even work.
Do you guys see the problem ? Because I don't get any errors in the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are doing it wrong. you are adding this click handler to every "a" element on page. you need to add this event only to your directive. which you can achieve as

```
var app = angular.module('App');

app.directive("scrollBottom", [function () {
return {
restrict: "A",
link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
    $(elem).click(function () {
        $("html, body").animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            });
        return false;
    });
 }
 }
}]);
```

by the way you are using your directive incorrectly on your html. camelCasing on a directive name converts to camel-casing on html.
so you need to use your directive as

```
scroll-bottom
```

edit: i simplified scrollTop code

Comment: What does the 'elem' means or how do I use it ?

Comment: you should read https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive .
elem is the second parameter of your link function. it is the current element that your directive is applied to

Comment: you are welcome :). i'd be glad if you dont forget to mark this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the camel case into dashes, like this:

```
<button scroll-bottom>Click me!</button>
```

You don't see any errors in the console because it is just a plain attribute that means nothing.

Comment: @Goldenowner That's a different thing, at least now you can see that your directive is working and you can debug to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Beside tha fact that you should call your directive not via

```
<button scrollBottom>Click me!</button>
```

but

```
<button scroll-bottom>Click me!</button>
```

you also have to check, in console should be an exception something like App module not available, that is vecause you have to change the directive creation from

```
angular.module('App');

App.directive
```

Into

```
var app = angular.module('App');

app.directive
```